# Deploying a c++ QT5 app

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to deploy my application. It works on Windows 7 with quit a lot of .dll files but I can't get it work on Windows XP. It seems that windows Xp requires more dll files. But the Dependency walker tool keeps showing me new dll files missing. Now it says API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-0.DLL and API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL are missing.

When i try to start the exe nothing happens ... no error...

I use Qt5.0.2 with pre build msvc2010.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, if you dig deep enough in Windows 7, those files do exist and most of them would indeed work on Windows XP... At least they did 3 years ago. The other way is to re-build Qt with lesser WINVER (or such) macro for this to work, but I dunno about Qt 5. Time to move on, or stick with older tools.

Comment: I also need to copy and paste all these dlls in the application folder?

Comment: Have a look at this thread as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370111/why-is-my-qt-application-not-working

Comment: And have you worked through the deployment guide at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html?

Comment: ok the soulution is to create a folder platforms and insert qwindows.dll relativ to the exe

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is related to missing VS 2010 redistributable?  Also make sure to build in a release-configuration if you don't already know.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

If you package this up into an installer like NSIS, I'd typically execute it with the argument /Q to prevent any GUIs from popping up... it won't ask for any admin privileges which is nice since the previous VC 2008 redistrib always required it.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer a requirement is the VS redistributable. In your case, as you use VS2010 the file to download is MS 2010 redistributable.

Besides of that there is the executable windeployqt that helps with the deployment package copying the Qt DLLs required on your executable directory.