# Runtime error for QT application?

Tags: windows, qt

I have developed an application on Qt5.1 for windows 7 and now I want to distribute it. Since I have used the MINGW compiler I cannot build it static. I used dependency walker to find out all the dlls and packaged it. When I run the application on a machine which doesnot have QT development environment installed the application crashes with Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error.

Could anybody please point me out the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about error?

Comment: I get an error which read Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library. This program has requested runtime to terminate it in an unusual way

Comment: I encounter this problem when `QVector at index of range`.Mingw have not show the error in the error Dialog And MSVC have. And Mingw have not locate the error line of code just emit a Runtime error Dialog with no detail msg.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The error was**

[image]

**Fixed the problem:**

The fix is add a folder *platform* into the location of your application executable and into that copy *qwindows.dll* from the loaction 5.1.0-rc2\mingw48_32\plugins\platforms of your QT installation.

Also all the dlls need to be copied!

Comment: It seems that folder should be ***platforms*** instead of *platform*

Comment: I believe this post saved me a lot of time trying to solve the exact same issue.. accept your own answer Prajosh!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have missed some DLLs. Try again with dependency walker, I have faced the same issue once. The dependency walker did not show missing DLLs but some were missing. Try to search in SO, there are similar questions.

[Do I have to include all these Qt dlls with my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736229/do-i-have-to-include-all-these-qt-dlls-with-my-application)

[How to run Qt 5 applications on other computers (Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198649/how-to-run-qt-5-applications-on-other-computers-windows-7)

Comment: Fixed the problem: The fix is add a folder platform and into that copy qwindows.dll 5.1.0-rc2\mingw48_32\plugins\platforms if release build or qwindowsd.dll for debug. Also all the dlls need to be copied

Comment: Qt5 is getting more convoluted by the minute.