# Qt application: Failed to load platform plugin “windows" on Windows 8 but no issues on Windows 7

Tags: windows, qt, dll

A lot of similar questions has been posted, but noone has worked for me. 
On Windows 7, i am able to run my program standalone with the appropriate dll's in the executables folder.

At Windows 8.1, I am not able to run my project either with Qt Creator nor standalone. I am getting the error

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "windows". Available platform plugins are: minimal,
>   offscreen.

I put my platform dll's in ./platforms and ./ as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268558/application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-pl) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291078/qt-application-failed-to-load-platform-plugin-windows-available-platforms-ar) amongst other places. Still, my application won't launch and gives me the same error.

I've included all dll's from my `C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0-mingw\5.2.0\mingw48_32\plugins\platforms` directory.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try platformS folder in the same path as your executable (there is an 's' at the end), on my Windows 7 system the MinGW Qt build runs without platforms/qwindows.dll, probably that is needed on Windows 8.

Comment: Edited that, I had actually used platform**s**

Answer (score 0):

For me, with installed Qt 5.2.0 and MSVC 2012, the following dll's were needed to execute app (Release version) on Windows 7 and 8.1 :

```
-example.exe //My application
-icudt51.dll
-icuin51.dll
-icuuc51.dll
-libEGL.dll
-libGLESv2.dll
-Qt5Core.dll
-Qt5Gui.dll
-Qt5Widgets.dll
-platforms // Folder
 --qminimal.dll
 --qoffscreen.dll
 --qwindows.dll
```

Comment: Somewhat irrelevant I think since I am using the mingw compiler

Comment: @Wilhelmsen Since you don't provide list of dll's that you used, I didn't know if it only qt creator+mingw problem or it's problem in included dll's. However, I must admit that I did not carefully read the question and missed the fact that your app not executes in QtCreator.